# jQuery parse huge response fail

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on an application that sends request to a url and parses the table present on the html in response using jQuery. While this seems to work quite nicely when the amount of html code being returned is reasonable, it somehow fails with big datsets.

The issue starts when

```
   $.get(url, function(response){
     $(response).find('table');
   })
```

returns an emtpy search result despite having a table in the response string.However the same piece code works just fine when tables are small (approximately 1000 columns)

Any idea how can this issue be tackled?

For testing purposes, I'm working with this dataset as of now, http://socr.ucla.edu/docs/resources/SOCR_Data/SOCR_Data_Dinov_020108_HeightsWeights.html

Any alternative suggestions to make this process a bit faster?

Comment: What is that `$(response)`, did it build a proper document (fragment)? Try logging `$(response)[0]` and inspect it. In which browser does this occur?

Comment: Note that jQuery itself doesn't do any parsing of the response - the browser does it. The library just arranges the details of that for you.

Comment: I've tested it in Firefox and Chrome v21, Here's an interesting screenshot of the chrome console http://ge.tt/9XZDVSP/v/0

Comment: The jQuery `find()` operation looks **inside** the element.  If the element *is* a `<table>`, then you won't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.get(url, function(response){
  var $response = $(response);
  var $table = $response.is('table') ? $response : $response.find('table');
  // ...

})
```

If the response HTML/XML is a `<table>`, then `find()` won't find it. It only looks at descendants of the element you start from. The code above checks to see whether you've already got the `<table>`.

Comment: Seems legitimate, the page was generated from x:str hence the response was a table. Thanks

Comment: Yes, and jQuery doesn't seem to build a document from your HTML string, but parses it like `innerHTML` - where doctypes, `<html>` or `<body>` tags are invalid